# MongoDB - joining two results of queries and dense_rank

Tags: mongodb, join, dense-rank

I'm learning about MongoDB and I have some problems with understanding its concept.

I have a collection which looks like that:

```
db.email.findOne()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("52af48b5d55148fa0c199646"),
        "sender" : "tori.wells@enron.com",
        "recipients" : [
                "michael@optsevents.com"
        ],
        "cc" : [ ],
        "text" : "Mr. Christman:\n\nThank you for your invitation for Dr. Lay to speak at your upcoming forum in \nFrance, the format looks wonderful.  Unfortunately, Dr. Lay has calendar \nconflicts and will be unable to participate.\n\nIf you should need further assistance, please do not hesitate to contact us.\n\nTori Wells\nExecutive Assistant",
        "mid" : "22263156.1075840285610.JavaMail.evans@thyme",
        "fpath" : "enron_mail_20110402/maildir/lay-k/_sent/101.",
        "bcc" : [ ],
        "to" : [
                "michael@optsevents.com"
        ],
        "replyto" : null,
        "ctype" : "text/plain; charset=us-ascii",
        "fname" : "101.",
        "date" : "2000-08-04 09:04:00-07:00",
        "folder" : "_sent",
        "subject" : "Wall Street Journal Millennium Forum"
}
```

It's the Enron database.

I'm trying to make a query which will return listed emails with amount of messages sent by it and amount of messages received by it.

I managed to make two queries which looks like that:

```
db.email.aggregate({$group:{_id:"$sender",SendsAmount:{$sum:1}}},{$sort:{SendsAmount:-1}})
{ "_id" : "rosalee.fleming@enron.com", "SendsAmount" : 849 }
{ "_id" : "brown_mary_jo@lilly.com", "SendsAmount" : 82 }
{ "_id" : "leonardo.pacheco@enron.com", "SendsAmount" : 78 }

db.email.aggregate({$group:{_id:"$recipients",ReceivedAmount:{$sum:1}}},{$unwind:"$_id"},{$sort:{ReceivedAmount:-1}})
{ "_id" : "klay@enron.com", "ReceivedAmount" : 1350 }
{ "_id" : "kenneth.lay@enron.com", "ReceivedAmount" : 912 }
{ "_id" : "kenneth.lay@enron.com", "ReceivedAmount" : 78 }
```

As you can see first one returns me emails and amount of emails sends from it and second one also returns emails and amount of received ones by it.

My point is to join(?) these two into one and get one query which will return something like:

```
{ "_id" : "email@enron.com", "SendsAmount" : 57, "ReceivedAmount": 43 }
```

I know there is $lookup but it can be used only with two collections, so my idea was to make two collections out of these two queries but I'm feeling like there is better way of solving my problem.

---My second problem is about trying to do some DENSE_RANK which is not present in MongoDB. I want to rank email adresses by amount of sent emails.

I used the $unwind and insertArrayIndex but I got something like ROW_NUMBER which is not I'm looking for.

I have written something like that:

```
db.email.aggregate({$group:{"_id":"$sender",SendsAmount:{$sum:1},rank:0}},{$sort:{"ile":-1}}).forEach(function(x){
                        var howmany=0;
                        var query=db.email.aggregate({$group:{"_id":"$sender",SendsAmount:{$sum:1}}},{$match:{ile:{$gt:x.SendsAmount}}},{$group:{_id:null, HowManyGreater:{$sum:1}}});
                        query.forEach(function(y){
                            howmany=y.HowManyGreater;
                        }); 
                        howmany=howmany+1;
                        print("email: "+ x._id + " SendsAmount: " + x.SendsAmount + " rank " + howmany+1);
                    });
```

Which is givig me the result I want, but it's not even the document but only printed information. I've read about MapReduce but I didn't get the idea how to use it in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do all calculations in aggregate query, you can use $facet and $group stages as below

```
db.email.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      send: [
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$sender",
            SendsAmount: {
              $sum: 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $sort: {
            SendsAmount: -1
          }
        }
      ],
      recieve: [
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$recipients",
            ReceivedAmount: {
              $sum: 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $unwind: "$_id"
        },
        {
          $sort: {
            ReceivedAmount: -1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      all: {
        $concatArrays: [
          "$recieve",
          "$send"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$all"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$all._id",
      ReceivedAmount: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: {
            if: {
              $gt: [
                "$all.ReceivedAmount",
                null
              ]
            },
            then: "$all.ReceivedAmount",
            else: 0
          }
        }
      },
      SendsAmount: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: {
            if: {
              $gt: [
                "$all.SendsAmount",
                null
              ]
            },
            then: "$all.SendsAmount",
            else: 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That's the result I wanted for my first problem, so all what I needed was $facet function, great! Do you have any idea for my second problem - the dense-rank query?

Comment: regarding the second problem do you want data sorted by no of SendsAmount and include array position(rank) in document itself?

Comment: Yes I want data sorted by no of SendsAmount but the rank cannot be exactly the array position. When there appear the same no of SendsAmount for i.e. two email adresses I need them to have the same rank and the array position will give me two different numbers for the same amount - that's the problem.

Comment: How about in your code instead of print create an empty array before aggregate and push in the array instead of print the object

Comment: Seems like a nice idea, I put this code instead of print(): ```rank={$push:{
        'email':x._id,
        'Recievedl':x.ReceivedAmount,
        'Rank':howmany
       }
      }```  but when it's done in my 'rank' variable I have something like this: ```{
        "$push" : {
                "email" : "coleen.a.hanna@constellation.com",
                "Received" : 1,
                "Rank" : 575
        }
}``` so I got only one element and with the '$push' and brackets as a text. So I think I'm doing this wrong, how to correctly push something into variable?

Comment: create an array say   let rank=[]; before aggregate and instead of print use rank.push({'email':x._id,'Recievedl':x.ReceivedAmount, 'Rank':howmany}) if you're using js

Comment: Works slow, but I got my solution thank you very much!